# Server - Client event push?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am working in a project there i have a Dashboard page. My requirement is to Push some message to all the client(Without any client request , based on some event occur in the server itself) who is currently connected with the server and with Dashboard page open in their system. Using Spring 3.2.x and hibernate 3 . How i will achieve and above requirement with Spring ?

Note: I can't go for polling as event can occur at any milli secs .

Comment: Hibernate is irrelevant here. You're looking for web sockets. Spring 4 has comprehensive support for them. Time to upgrade. Spring 3 is old, and so is Hibernate 3. http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#_websocket_sockjs_and_stomp_messaging. That said, I don't see why you couldn't use polling. The fact that an event can happen at any time is irrelevant. What matters is how many messages can be pushed per second, and how long you're ready to wait before seeing a new message.

Comment: @JB Nizet : Thanks for your reply. 
Event at server side can occur at any time , it may in milli sec, secs , hours  or days. So now is it relevant to go for polling ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are at Spring 3 and can't/don't want to use WebSockets (which are the best way to push data fast to the client), I recommend **Long-Polling**.

Long-Polling is similar to polling, but the difference is that in the first polling call, the HTTP request does not complete immediately.

This means that when a client connects to your Dashboard, **a connection remains open until there is an event to report**. At the time of the event, it is reported immediately which means that you **avoid the delay in traditional polling**.

Long-polling can be implemented very easily in Spring, just use the built-in class `DeferredResult`.

You can see this tutorial from the Spring page, which is very complete.
[Adding Long-Polling to an existing Web Application](https://spring.io/blog/2012/05/14/spring-mvc-3-2-preview-adding-long-polling-to-an-existing-web-application)

This solution is compatible with Spring 3.2.